# HTC One X IMAP marking emails as read

Tags: email, htc-one-x, imap

I've synced my yahoo account to my HTX one X's mail client using IMAP which syncs regularly every 15 minutes, however if i've not looked at the phone for a while the email will mark itself as read and the notification disappears so i'm missing new emails if i dont open the client regularly. Is there anyway to stop this from happening?